# Retrieving Object ID

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am looking for a way to retrieve information on a user in my data table using Parse for IOS. I am new to this so not sure what the syntax is for doing so, but I'm looking for a way to search the username from the Username column in the table and retrieve the object id for that user. I plan on using the Object ID to get the Password column along with the other information I need.

Here is pretty much all I've been able to figure out by now:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"LoginInformation"];
[query whereKey:@[@"Username"] equalTo:@"Steve"];
```

However I think I am doing this horribly wrong. Any help would be great!

Comment: Why have you put the key in an array? And why are you trying to get the password?

Comment: I am actually not sure how to retrieve the user Steve from the Username column. And I am trying to retrieve the Password to authenticate the user.

Comment: You can't, you authenticate them by logging them in and that returns the user

Comment: Oh, I see! Could you provide some sample code or reference to some sample code where I can get a better idea of what you're talking about!

Thanks so far for the help Wain

Comment: What you are doing is a really bad idea! That is a huge security issue if you allow you clients to read the actual password field! If you don't know any better you should use parse's ready to use login system

Answer (score 1):

Please read this:

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users

In the sections **Signing up** and **Logging in** you will find the sample code you need!

Comment: Thank you so much Nils, didn't even see this!